# Menu Moves Itself

Tags: css, menu

Would anyone kindly be able to advise why the bottom-right menu moves up the page when the Mixcloud or Youtube icons are clicked?

I've tried amending various parts with no success.

http://www.jameswinfield.co.uk/v2.html#

The code is:

```
.menu4 {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.menu4 nav {
  -webkit-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  -ms-opacity: 0;
  -o-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu4 input#slide4:checked ~ nav {
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  -ms-opacity: 1;
  -o-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu4 label {
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.menu4 input#slide4 {
  display: none;
}

.menu4 input#slide4:checked ~ label.open i {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.menu4 label i,
.menu4 nav,
.menu4 nav ul li a span {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu4 label,
.menu4 nav ul li a i,
.menu4 nav ul li a span {
  line-height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

.menu4 nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu4 nav ul li a i {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.menu4 nav ul li a span {
  font-family: 'Lato', tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17.14285714px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 0;
}

.menu4 nav ul li a:hover span {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.menu4 nav ul li.active a span {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.menu4.top {
  bottom: 0px;
}

.menu4.bottom {
  bottom: 0px;
}

.menu4.left,
.menu4.left label {
  right: 0;
}

.menu4.right,
.menu4.right label {
  right: 0;
}

.menu4.horizontal nav ul li,
.menu4.horizontal nav ul li a span {
  float: left;
}

.menu4.left.horizontal nav {
  margin-right: -50px;
}

.menu4.left.horizontal input#slide4:checked ~ nav {
  margin-right: 120px;
}

.menu4.right.horizontal nav {
  margin-right: -60px;
}

.menu4.right.horizontal input#slide4:checked ~ nav {
  margin-right: 60px;
}


.menu4.blue label,
.menu4.blue nav ul li a ul li i {
  color: #F82D27;

}

.menu4.blue nav ul li a span {
  color: #F235E9;
}

.mixcloud {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.youtube {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is not as it seems. On a wide screen your site is fine. When I scale it down I can see your reported problem. But then I also saw that the problem is not the youtube  or cloud items. This problem happens when you click on the containing element of your bottom right menu icon. I'll see if I can help more but that should shed some light at least.

Comment: Nevermind I misinterpreted the situation my bad. Can you explain what you want to happen instead? Do you want the video frame to display above those icons?

Comment: are you Questioning when you close the music icon it is not coming or moving down?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I do not want the music icon to go up in the first place - I want the videos to display above the icons if possible please.